# SwiftUI: Finding the best way to map API Response

Tags: swift, swiftui

I start to learn SwiftUI. Now I am thinking about the best way to map API Response in a `ObservableObject`.

First of all, this is the API Response:

```
{
    "food": [
        "fish",
        "meat"
    ],
    "go": [
        "London",
        "Bangkok"
    ],
    "party": [
        "Family",
        "Friends"
    ]
}
```

This is my `ObservableObject`:

```
struct MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var food: [String]
    var go: [String]
    var party: [String]

    func fetchTagMeResponse() {
        let url = URL(string: "domain.com/api/tagmes/")
        var result = nil
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, res, err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO MAP IT?
            }
        }.resume()
        return result
    }

}
```

As you see, I need the best way to **handle data response after getting it from API** in the line of code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO MAP IT?
}
```

**My Solution**

I am thinking about use `Decodable` and I think it is not the best way. Because if I wont use `MyResponse` anymore. Is it unnecessary?

```
struct MyResponse: Decodable {
   var food: [String]
   var go: [String]
   var party: [String]
}
```

Tell me if you guys have a better solution for this.

Comment: "I am thinking about use Decodable and I think it is not the best way." why not?

Comment: You should use `Decodable`

Comment: if I wont use `MyResponse` anymore. Is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Combine to to do so. By the way, it is better to use Codable as it is made by Apple to lift the hard work for you. It is a powerful tool.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

//MARK: - Your model
struct MyResponse: Identifiable, Codable {
  let id: Int
  var food: [String]
  var go: [String]
  var party: [String]
}

//MARK: - Your network manager
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {

  @Published var myResponseFood = [String]()
  @Published var myResponseGo = [String]()
  @Published var myResponseParty = [String]()

  func fetchTagMeResponse() {
    _ = URLSession.shared
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "domain.com/api/tagmes/")!)
      .map(\.data)
      .decode(type: MyResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
        if case .failure(let error) = completion {
          print("You have an error: \(error)")
        }
      }, receiveValue: { (object) in
        //MARK: - Your map objects are here
        self.myResponseFood = object.food
        self.myResponseGo = object.go
        self.myResponseParty = object.party
      })
  }
}

//MARK: - Your SwiftUI view
struct MyViewModel: View {

  @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(networkManager.myResponseParty) { party in
        Text(party)
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      self.networkManager.fetchTagMeResponse()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my NetworkManager class you for me its best approach for handling API's in SwiftUI

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<NetworkManager,Never>()

    var courses = [Course](){
        didSet{
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://myDomain/courses") else{ return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else { return }
            let courses = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self , from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.courses =  courses

                debugPrint(self.courses)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

// This is how i'm binding the data.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(networkManager.courses, id: \.id) { course in
                    RowUI(course: course)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Courses"))
        }
    }
}
```